# Automatically identify the most extreme visible breakpoints in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Density fits provide a neat way to visualize an underlying distribution that doesn't involve grouping data like histograms do. Unfortunately, the y scale produced by this has little intuitive meaning. For instance,

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length)) + geom_density()
```

[image]

The y axis has no particular intuitive interpretation like the histogram with fractions has:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length)) + stat_bin(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)))
```

[image]

Because I keep getting queries from reviewers about the meaning of the numbers in the y axis on density plots, I decided that I want to get rid of them and replace them with endpoints that simply go "lower", "higher". One way to almost do this is as follows:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length)) + geom_density() + scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) {
    x = rep("", length(x))
    x[1] = "lower"
    x[length(x)] = "higher"
    x
}) + theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

In this case we were lucky. The last breakpoint has "higher". But this doesn't always happen. Consider another variable from the same dataset:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width)) + geom_density() + scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) {
    x = rep("", length(x))
    x[1] = "lower"
    x[length(x)] = "higher"
    x
}) + theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Now the "higher" is missing. The explanation seems to be that that the last breakpoint that was auto-generated happened to be outside the view. One can fix the issue by manually setting limits:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width)) + geom_density() + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.2), labels = function(x) {
    x = rep("", length(x))
    x[1] = "lower"
    x[length(x)] = "higher"
    x
}) + theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
```

(also works using `coord_cartesian`).

One can work out where the last breakpoint is by plotting the data with the y axis values present, of course.

[image]

However, I am looking for an automatic way to avoid the issue. The trouble is that figuring out what the highest visible breakpoint will be is not so straightforward.

Comment: The y-axis does mean something in a density plot. Since the integral of the density is 1, it's reasonably easy to interpret if it's flat between two integers. For instance, in the `Sepal.Length` plot, about 40% of the data is between 5 and 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hacky solution:

```
g1 = ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_density()  + 
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())


g2 = ggplot2::ggplot_build(g1)
max_density = g2$data[[1]]$density %>% max()

g1 + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, max_density), labels = function(x) {
  x = rep("", length(x))
  x[1] = "lower"
  x[length(x)] = "higher"
  x
})
```

So, we draw the plot. Then reverse engineer it. Then find the maximum density that will be plotted. Then manually set the upper breakpoint equal to that value. It works, but it is slow and it seems like there should be a better way to do this.